# Python: my polynomial coefficients are off by a factor of 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, polynomial-math

I am learning scientific computing with python. In the exercise, I am supposed to generate a polynomial by using its roots with this formula:

[image]

Here is my implementation:

```
def poly(x,roots):            #Pass real and/or complex roots

    x = symbols(x)
    f = 1            
    for r in roots:
        f = f*(x - r)

    return expand(f)
```

When I test it:

```
from sympy import expand
poly('x',[(-1/2), 5, (21/5), (-7/2) + (1/2)*sqrt(73), (-7/2) - (1/2)*sqrt(73)])
```

I get:

```
x**5 - 1.7*x**4 - 50.5*x**3 + 177.5*x**2 - 24.8999999999999*x - 63.0
```

But I should get:

```
10*x**5 - 17.0*x**4 - 505.0*x**3 + 1775.0*x**2 - 248.999999999999*x - 630.0
```

Hence, everything is off by a factor of 10. If I set `f = 10`, it works, but I don't see why I should do that. Am I making an obvious mistake? Thank you!

Comment: The formula is not showing up. Can you fix this please?

Comment: what does symbols() do?

Comment: You are constructing polynomial with specific roots. If you multiply it's coeffs to any number, the roots will remains the same.

Comment: @EliSadoff Oups! thank you for mentioning it. :)

Comment: @matiaselgart Hi! It's supposed to make Python treat 'x' as an algebraic variable. That's how I was shown, but is there a better way?

Comment: @Jonathan you shouldn't be getting 10*x**5, the above answer is correct and you can verify this by plugging in all the roots and seeing that for each `x`, `p(x)=0`. While this will also be true with `10 * p(x)`, there's no reason to do this.

Comment: @EliSadoff OH! I see now: I don't know why I didn't realize this obvious mistake. The authors chose those coefficients, but I have the form with the most reduced coefficients. Thank you!!!

Comment: @EliSadoff Also, if you post your answer, I'll chose it.

Comment: No worries. I'm a scientific computing guy, so I like helping out with this stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `10x**5 + ...` is correct, that is `10 * p(x)`, which isn't really what is needed. The answer you are getting is fine right now as well and you can test that as for each `r` in `roots`, `p(r)` is `0`.

Comment: I tested each root. As the book warns me, due to floating-point rounding errors, I get very small numbers close to zero. If please possible, do you have a preferred technique to correct this?

Comment: @Johnathan You'll generally get floating point errors. I generally set a tolerance of `1e-12` and `abs(p(r)) < 1e-12`, you should be fine. Read more about it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken?rq=1).

Answer (score 0):

`x**5` is correct.

As you can see in the formula, there's no coefficient for it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!